# Can sp2010 managed metadata be captured using sp2013 search?

Tags: sharepoint-search

Can sp2010 managed metadata be captured using sp2013 search?  We are using 2013 search on sp2010 portals.  The users were using the Advanced Search property restrictions with great success and now that we are about to move to sp2013 search for the 2010 portals I fear that this feature may not be available.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

[image]